# How to put double quotes in other double quotes

Tags: r, tidyverse, double-quotes

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Here is the representation of my dataset:

```
mydata<-data.frame(NCT_number=c(" 1111","  2222","0000","3333","4444 ")
```

I want to spots characters that are preceded or followed by blanks: One space, two spaces and so on.
I tried this:

```
mydata%>%filter(str_detect(NCT_number,c(" " "|"  " ")))
```

My expected result is:

```
  NCT_number
1       1111
2       2222
5      4444
```

But it didn't works.

Comment: Could you please make the question reproducible, provide some sample data: paste the output of `dput(head(mydata$NCT_number, 10))` into the question, as a minimum and included your expected outcome.

Comment: Use the backslash to escape it. `\"`

Comment: Can you please update the title as in its present form it is far from reflecting the actual content of your question

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>%
  filter(grepl("^\\s|\\s$", NCT_number))
  NCT_number
1       1111
2       2222
3      4444
```

Here we are making use of the 'anchors' `^`, which denotes the start position of the string, and `$`, which denotes the end position of the string.

With `base R`:

```
mydata[grepl("^\\s|\\s$", mydata$NCT_number),]
[1] " 1111"  "  2222" "4444 "
```